# Compare each excel sheets with a table in oracle

Tags: python, java, excel, oracle

I have an xlsx file and I have loaded most of the sheets in transposed manner in oracle.

Ex:-
Xlsx :

| Roll no | Name. | Age | Job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Harshita | 25 | IT |

Oracle :

| Roll No | Parame | Param_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Harshita |
| 1 | Age | 25 |
| 1 | Job | IT |

Now, in oracle table, roll no 1 has three rows where as in xlsx it has 1.
How to verify if the count is right and and the value is same when comparing the table data with the sheets?

Is there a way to write a script to compare the sheets with tables after loading the data?

I tried macros but that is not possible for me to put in prod as the sheets will change every 6 months and I tried few queries like groupBy.

Answer (score 0):

One way to verify the count and value of the data is to use SQL queries to compare the data between the Oracle table and the xlsx sheet.

1. First, you need to create a new table in Oracle that has the same
   structure as the xlsx sheet.
2. Import the xlsx data into this new table.
3. Use a SQL query to compare the count of rows in both the tables, and
   to verify that the values in both the tables are the same. For
   example:

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xlsx_table
> UNION 
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oracle_table;
> ```

4. If the count is not the same, then use another
   query to find out which rows are missing:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM xlsx_table
> MINUS 
> SELECT * FROM oracle_table;
> ```

5. If the values are not the same, then use another query to find out which values are different:

> ```
> SELECT xlsx_table.*, oracle_table.* FROM xlsx_table, oracle_table 
> WHERE xlsx_table.roll_no = oracle_table.roll_no 
> AND (xlsx_table.name != oracle_table.name 
> OR xlsx_table.age != oracle_table.age 
> OR xlsx_table.job != oracle_table.job)
> ```

By using these queries, you can verify the count and values of the data and make sure that the data has been loaded correctly.

Comment: I can't load xlsx into oracle because each sheet has different structure that is different no of columns and that is why I have transposed the data in the way it's mentioned. For ex. If one sheet has roll no, name, age, job. Other might have roll no, address, phone no. But roll no will always be there in all the sheets. So, to have it structured I transposed the data in a manner that all the columns and their values except roll no will come as rows respectively.

Comment: if you can't load xlsx in oracle then I think you need a python script that connects to both the xlsx file and the Oracle database, retrieves the data and compares the count and values.

Comment: Upon your suggestion, I can combine each spreadsheet and dump it into a csv, and then create an external table on top of it by adding the audit columns and then compare. That way I don't have to work on retrieval of data from xlsx and oracle because it can get messy.

Comment: Yes, combining each spreadsheet into a CSV and creating an external table on top of it with audit columns is a good solution. This way, you can easily compare the data without having to retrieve it from xlsx and oracle separately. This approach also eliminates the need for complex macros and queries, making it easier to maintain and update as needed. then I suppose I will delete my answer as I don't think you need SQL queries hope you solve your question have a good day